# Magento products packs (assortiment) with size and stock control - like 3-pack or 6-pack

Tags: configurable-product, bundled-product, grouped-products

Suppose we sell socks. In sizes S, M and L.

Currently we use

- 1 configurable product
- That is linked to 3 simple products, each with its own stock
- If a sale is made stock is deducted from the simple product by qty #

Now we would like to create packs of the individual configurable product, say "buy 6 pairs of socks" for price Y.

I can imagining creating 1 product, that

- works the same as a configurable product, where
- a customer has to select his/her size
- but when a sale is made of 1 product (the 6 pack or 8 pack for that matter)
- then 6 pieces are deducted from the simple product qty # (instead of 6)

**Question**: can this be done out of the box? Or is an extension required?

The major element to understand is that one wants to create a new standalone configurable prodcuts (say a T-shirt) where a customer would just like normal select the size and the qty and click add to cart. Only if the product was created as "pack" and has a value ons tock level for a new attribute say "products in pack" (which defaults to 1) then the title of the product can be something like "6 pack t-shirts" and the image shows 6 T-shirts etc.etc. You enter qty=1 (because you want ot buy 1 pack) but the backend order processing should register 6*qty ("products in pack"=6 in this example) when changing the underlying simple products stock. So all values of the configurable product work natively, but not the stock this is influenced by the "products in pack" attribute.

thx!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could create the "6 pack" product as a bundle with one required dropdown option, call it "size". Add the S, M and L simple products as selections for this option with a default qty of 6 and "custom qty = no".

Now the customer can choose the size just as with the configurable product, and the number of packs with the bundle qty input.

Note that this approach does not work anymore if you have multiple configurable attributes (size and color)

Comment: At least it is possible at all! Have you ever encountered extension that made it possible?

Comment: There are a few extensions around that advertise with extended product types like "configurable bundle" but I did not check them out, so I cannot give a recommendation.

Comment: Thanks. I did check quite a few. None do the real bundle like above.

Comment: And with your bundle suggestion. Could they order two bundles of 6? Being 12 pieces in total do you think?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with the bundle qty input. This is the qty the user can choose (2 in this case)

Comment: This isn't working as expected. It doesn't show the size option but that could be template related. The main caveat is that the size drop down does not show S M L but rather the nonsexy name of the simple product.

Comment: Ah right, you cannot change the label. But that's also something you can solve in the template

Comment: Yep true. But we also expose our products to cps and cpc networks and that would involve a whole lot of coding. Thx for the help!